# What is this beetle? Found in heather in snowdonia

Tags: entomology, species-identification

We were walking in the hills of snowdonia the other day and my girlfriend found this in the heather:

[image]

I've never seen anything like it. Can anyone identify it? It was the biggest beetle I've ever seen.

Comment: Ah, the rare *Dimentium stupidus*. It's legs contain a special chemical that makes you impotent and turns your mind to mush. They're harmless otherwise, just don't let one crawl on your bare skin.

Comment: That's fine, it was my girlfriends hand! @OlinLathrop ha ha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it's the [Violet Ground Beetle](http://www.eakringbirds.com/eakringbirds5/insectinfocusvioletgroundbeetle.htm) - 
*Carabus violaceus*. This is a close relative to the *Carabus coriaceus* posted by [Jon](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/6595/2090).

The purple colour is a give away, but as in many insect groups there are often very similar species. As pointed out in the comments to this anwer, this is the case for *C. violaceus* and *C. problematicus* ([differences](http://www.thewcg.org.uk/idaids/cproblematicusviolaceus.htm))

There are websites  like [observado.org](http://observado.org/) where sightings can be added as a species or for instance "unknown beetle", where they are reviewed (depending on the availability of the volunteering experts) or identified.

Comment: Great answer! Yes I think your correct. Something about the other option didn't quite add up. The violet was very prominent.

Comment: In the key I use for the Netherlands, I remember there is a very similar species to the Carabus violaceus, I think it is Carabus problematicus. but I can not find my key now so I can not tell you the differences.

Comment: ah of course there is a internet page about the differences: http://www.thewcg.org.uk/idaids/cproblematicusviolaceus.htm, based on your picture I think I see the longitudinal granulations, so I tend towards C. problematicus...

Answer (score 3):

I would say that it is a **Carabus coriaceus**. It might have a size of 30 to 40mm and is very common around Europe.

[image]

Unfortunately the English wikipedia article is rather tiny: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carabus_coriaceus